# output awk command result to variable

Tags: awk

i ran the following command from console it output the correct result:`0`,

```
sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report | grep 'Under replicated blocks' | awk '{print \$4}'"
```

however if i put it in shell script and assigned it to a variable the 'awk' won't work anymore, it just output the whole result from 'grep':

```
replications=`sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report | grep 'Under replicated blocks' | awk '{print \$4}'"`
echo "Replications: $replications"
```

result: `Replications: Under replicated blocks: 0`
how can i make the awk work again to only output 4th column which is 0 instead of the whole string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In backtick command substitution, `\` followed by `$` means just `$`. From the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) standard:

> Within the backquoted style of command substitution, backslash shall retain its literal meaning, except when followed by: '$', '`', or '\' (dollar sign, backquote, backslash). (...)
>
> With the `$(command)` form, all characters following the open parenthesis to the matching closing parenthesis constitute the command. Any valid shell script can be used for command, except a script consisting solely of redirections which produces unspecified results.

And yet more explicitly from the bash manpage:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or \.  The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.  When using the `$(command)` form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

So the easiest way is to use

```
replications=$(sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report | grep 'Under replicated blocks' | awk '{print \$4}'")
```

but

```
replications=`sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report | grep 'Under replicated blocks' | awk '{print \\\$4}'"`
```

also works.